# In Ruby, must instance variables (of a class) be first defined in "initialize" before it will work?

Tags: ruby, oop

```
class Shape
    def initialize()
        @blah = ""
    end
end
```

OR...will this work?

```
class Shape
    @blah = ""
    def initialize()

    end
end
```

Also, by default, are the instance variables public or private? How do you set them as public or private?

Answer (score 3):

Your second example initializes `@blah` as a class variable. It wouldn't be directly accessible (it'd need a class accessor) and would be the same across all instances of a class.

Instance variables are private-ish by nature, though you can get access to them with `@foo.instance_variable_get("@blah")`. Conventionally, if you want to access a `@blah` instance variable, you would add an accessor.

```
class Shape
  attr_accessor :blah
end
```

That would let you say, for example, `shape = Shape.new; shape.blah = "whee"; puts shape.blah` (and you'd get "whee").

Comment: A class variable would be @@blah.

Comment: i feel that your lastname should be "herald", not "heald". As it is it feels like it's missing something (notably an 'r'). Likewise your answer is missing something...The correct terminology is "class instance variable" not simply "class variable" (which would be @@blah as kiamlaluno correctly points out)

Comment: You're both correct. I should avoid SO when tired. And you wouldn't believe the number of telemarketers that pronounce it "Herald". :D

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables don't have to be defined anywhere, you can just start using them.  But be careful *where* you use them.  Your third example isn't what you want at all.

```
class Something
  @var = 10
end
```

This refers to an instance variable *of the class Something*, not an instance variable of any instance of Something.  Just remember not to refer to instance variables outside of the instance methods.